# Text Pages Formatting

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

I would like to recreate the boxes with text in them (you can see them on the picture below) I have access to the html part but when i paste it on a new page, they appear as bullet instead of boxes:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appear to be an issue with the way in which you have written the markup. Maybe you are missing some css classes.